# Select Count Group and Output into Array with Key and Value

Tags: php, arrays

I'm looking to select all rows from my database where `number_id = 1` and group the **experience** id's together and output the count of each in to an array with the experience `id` as the key and the `count` as the value.

```
+------------+------------+
| number_id  | experience |
+------------+------------+
|  1         |  4         |
|  1         |  4         |
|  1         |  1         |
|  1         |  2         |
|  1         |  3         |
|  1         |  1         |
|  1         |  5         |
+------------+------------+
```

So the results should be:

```
4 => 2
1 => 2
2 => 1
3 => 1
5 => 1
```

This is what I have so far:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS SUM FROM comments WHERE number_id = '1' GROUP BY experience";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$experience = array();
if ($result->num_rows>0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $experience[] = $row['SUM'];
    }
}

print_r($experience);
```

which outputs this

```
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 2 [2] => 1 [3] => 1 [5] => 1 )
```

but I need to be able to change they array key to be the experience id

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just select `experience` and use it as key.

```
$query = "SELECT experience, COUNT(*) AS SUM FROM comments WHERE number_id = '1' GROUP BY experience";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$experience = array();
if ($result->num_rows>0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $experience[$row['experience']] = $row['SUM'];
    }
}

print_r($experience);
```

Comment: `array_column(mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC), 'sum', 'experience');`